# AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'sjoin_nearest'

Tags: pandas, pyspark, bigdata, attributeerror, geopandas

I am trying to run below statement in databricks notebook but I am getting error as "
AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'sjoin_nearest'"

Is there anyone who can help me to resolve this?

```
final_gdf = gpd.sjoin_nearest(gdf1, gdf2, how = 'inner',lsuffix= 'left', rsuffix = 'right')
```

Comment: What is your version of `geopandas`? `print(gpd.__version__)`

Answer (score 2):

`sjoin_nearest` is a feature available from GeoPandas >= 0.10.

Try to upgrade:

```
[...]$ pip install -U geopandas

# Or

[...]$ conda update geopandas
```

Read the [Changelog](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/changelog.html#version-0-10-0-october-3-2021)

> A new sjoin_nearest() method to join based on proximity, with the ability to set a maximum search radius (#1865). In addition, the sindex attribute gained a new method for a “nearest” spatial index query (#1865, #2053).